# How can I solve TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to encode an image in base64 so I can save it as a string to the database. Using django, I get whatever is in the form data from the POST request. To specify the image,  i used a file input tag and changed the enctype to multipart/form-data. But I get this error:
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile`
I know there is another page with the same question, but i feel it does not solve my problem seeing i don't handle the file because it is only an image. I have tried going to other sites but they dont seem as helpful as much

This is the registration form where you can see there is a file input tag

```
    <div class="login-cont">
        <h1>Register!</h1>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Which state did you study in?" class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="school" placeholder="What university/college did you attend" class="form-control">
                <input type="file" name="propic" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile" placeholder="Choose photo..">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the view that handles it

```
    def signup(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST["username"]
            fullname = request.POST["fullname"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            email = request.POST["email"]
            area = request.POST["area"]
            school = request.POST["school"]
            propic = request.FILES["propic"]
    
            with open(propic, 'rb') as binary_file:
                binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
                base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_file_data)
                base64_message = base64_encoded_data.decode('utf-8')
    
                print(base64_message)
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, area=area, school=school, propic=propic)
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, "alumnas/register.html", {
                    'message':"Username taken"
                })
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "alumnas/register.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because you are trying to open the [uploaded file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/) using it as a path (look your traceback).

The uploaded file is usually stored in memory and already ready to work, so you don't need (and you almost can not) open it directly.

So, instead of doing

```py
 with open(propic, 'rb') as binary_file:
                binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
```

do

```py
binary_file_data = propic.read()
```

Also you make take a look for Django documentation how to [work with files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/) to use the best practices about using files, this may be much easier than storing base64 representation in the DB.